# Scope problem? - variable declaration is lost when don from within a sourced block, inside a bash function

Tags: bash, source

Facing an issue for which am running out of answers.
I stripped my issue to a simpler version for the purpose of the example:

I have a file called `datasource`, with the following contents:

```
$ cat datasource
declare X="Hello, world"
$
```

and the function foo declared as:

```
$ function foo( ) {
  . ./datasource
}
```

When I source datasource from the current context, X is declared; when I do it via foo, is not.

```
$ # next result is expected
$ unset X
$ declare -p X
bash: declare: X: not found
$
$ # next result is expected
$ . ./datasource
$ declare -p X
declare -- X="Hello, world"
$
$ # next result is NOT expected
$ unset X
$ foo
$ declare -p X
bash: declare: X: not found
$
```

Any idea why?

I am running Ubuntu LTS 18.04 and bash 5.0.17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `declare -g` to make the variable global. `help declare` says:

> When used in a function, *declare* makes NAMEs local, as with the *local*
> command.  The `-g` option suppresses this behavior.

Comment: Thanks! That was that in fact.... :)